# Use cell text to build Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to utilize a row and a column header to build a function that I can fill across an excel table (range of cells, not excel table object).  So, for example I have a row header "BAT61" and column headers "A","B","C"...

I'd like to create a formula that generates the following results in those columns: =min(BAT61A),=min(BAT61B), =min(BAT61C)... Where those generated names match named ranges that have already been created.

I've attempted to use =index without success (I generally get a #ref error).  I'd prefer a non-vba solution, if at all possible.  Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
  I've tried the indirect function but gotten the same #ref error.  I've verified that the named range exactly matches the text string I'm trying to pass.  I've tried the following variations with the same result #ref: =min(indirect(A1))[where A1 is the cell with "BAT61A"], =min(indirect(BAT61A))[to try and get the result directly], and =min(indirect(A1&A2))[where A1="BAT61" and A2="A"].  But, when I create a "Test" range, like suggested-it works.  Any further ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE2:  I was able to get it working with several slight modifications.  My named ranges that did't work were actually referring to fairly extensive array formulas that were parsing select rows from a table.  When I created new dummy columns in the table that basically did the filtering, the indirect would pull the correct columns based upon the indirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name some cells "Test" then you can use:

=MIN(INDIRECT("Test"))

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm

The name can be constructed using the & operator = $A1&B$2

Comment: it's called string concatenation and just to be sure, if headers are in first row: `=$A1&B$1`

Comment: This answer didn't completely solve my problem, but it defintely pointed me in the right direction (correct function and great resource at cpearson).  Thanks Chriseyre2000.

Answer (score 1):

For reference of others, use the function "***Address***" and "***Indirect***" in combination to achieve the above behavior.

Here is a sample for using values in cells to create formulas

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(E6,K2))
```

Assuming cell

> **E6** holds **3** and
> **K2** holds **4**

The above formula will return

```
=INDIRECT($C$4)
```

Assuming cell

> **C4** holds **This is a test**

The above formula will return

```
This is a test
```